# Xpath and CSSselector for two divs with the same html structure

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have two divs. The requirement is I need to click the Upload Buttons. I need to find the xpath of the first div and second div by checking the Button text Upload and then I need to click on it. So how to find the xpath of the divs and click on it. Is there a CSSselector also available for the same?

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-upload"/>
      Upload
  </button>
<a href="SomeLinkHere">
<button class="btn" type="button">Cancel</button>
</a>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-upload"/>
      Upload
  </button>
<a href="SomeLinkHere">
<button class="btn" type="button">Cancel</button>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry try this //i[contains(text(),'Upload')]

Comment: @sameerjoshi this wont work because "Upload" is under <button> tag not under <i>

Comment: @Melvin Richard   in above replace tag i with button and try if it dont works then try this //button[@type,'submit'].click();  hope it works

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following XPath:

```
//div[./button/i[contains(text(), 'Upload')]]
```

This XPath will return the `div` elements.

**EDIT:** To get the `button` element

```
//button[./i[contains(text(), 'Upload')]]
```

Comment: Hello Jason, This is not working. Because the <i> tag is closed before the Upload. So basically Upload is written under the button tag.

Comment: @MelvinRichard - I got your point. But I would like to ask one question. Are you using selenium-webdriver or the SeleniumIDE?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to install selenium ide for firefox. It has built-in element locator which proves to be useful in cases like yours.

I tried rendering the html code you provided in jsfiddle.net and I managed to get their xpath using selenium ide. You can see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlTBS.png)